# Python flask-sqlalchemy causes memory leak

Tags: python, flask, memory, memory-leaks, sqlalchemy

I'm intentionally using an infinite loop to generate math problems for a database. The program is meant to run for a long time and crashes once it reaches a memory limit. Here's my code.

```
def auto_generate():
    tracemalloc.start()
    while 0 == 0:
        gen_id = random.randint(0, len(mathgen.getGenList())-1)
        try:
            p, a, s = generate_problem(gen_id)
            # print(p)
        except Exception as e:
            with open("gen_errors.txt", "a") as myfile:
                myfile.write(sys.exc_value)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
        print("3: " + str(current))
        print("--------------------------")

def generate_problem(gen_id):
    poster = User.query.filter_by().first()
    gen_list = mathgen.getGenList()
    prob, ans = mathgen.genById(gen_id)
    print("1: " + str(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()[0]))
    generator_name = gen_list[gen_id][1]
    # If statement makes sure there isnt a duplicate
    if Problem.query.filter_by(question=prob).first() == None: 
        Problem.create(
            question=prob,
            answer=ans,
            poster_id=poster.id,
            correctnessRating=1,
            sortRating=1,
            difficultyLevel=None,
            expectedTime=None,
            hasSolution=True,
        )
        thisProb = Problem.query.filter_by(question=prob).first()
        # Add the math skill
        thisProb.skills.append(Skill.query.filter_by(id=1).first())
        # If generator_name skill doesn't yet exist, create it and then add it
        if Skill.query.filter_by(skillName=generator_name).first() == None:
            Skill.create(
                skillName = generator_name
            )
        thisProb.skills.append(Skill.query.filter_by(skillName=generator_name).first())
        # Add generated tag in order to prevent disaster if a bad generator is made
        thisProb.skills.append(Skill.query.filter_by(skillName="generated").first())
        db.session.commit()
        print("2: " + str(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()[0]))
        return prob, ans, generator_name
    else:
        return "Problem already exists", "N/A", "N/A"
```

I used tracemalloc to get memory usage at different parts of the program, which you can see in the code. Memory usage is around 2,400,000 when the program starts. It jumps around 20,000 between 1 and 2, drops around 10,000 between 2 and 3, and drops around 5,000 between 3 and 1. Here's a small sample:

```
--------------------------
1: 5003061
2: 5024667
3: 5019827
--------------------------
1: 5011095
2: 5032957
3: 5028117
--------------------------
1: 5019388
3: 5025709
--------------------------
1: 5021058
2: 5042896
3: 5038056
--------------------------
1: 5029159
3: 5035480
--------------------------
1: 5030912
3: 5037249
--------------------------
1: 5032638
2: 5054292
3: 5049452
--------------------------
```

Why am I having this problem, and how do I fix it? Is this a problem because of the infinite loop?

Edit:
Here are the results of checking the memory before and after the generate_problem function is ran:

```
--------------------------
Before: 5004703
After: 5008962
--------------------------
Before: 5008962
After: 5010523
--------------------------
Before: 5010523
After: 5012050
--------------------------
Before: 5012050
After: 5019269
--------------------------
Before: 5019269
After: 5027663
--------------------------
Before: 5027663
After: 5035639
--------------------------
Before: 5035639
After: 5039469
--------------------------
```

Comment: I think you need to add first check before generate_problem function called, thus you can have idea how much memory generate_problem function leaked

Comment: Where is db defined?

Comment: @Bey It is imported from another file where it is initialized. This is a multi-file flask application.

Comment: @LukeWeiler ok — i think that is relevant. There is a lot going on here. I’d suggest commenting out code to get a minimal version that still exhibits this issue then repost if the issue doesn’t become obvious.

Comment: @galaxyan I added the results to my question

Comment: @Bey I think you're right. I tried simplifying to get rid of all of the database operations and the leak cleared.

Comment: The issue with Python is that is garbage collects its own variables but if your database code is a wrapper around some binary executable then it can't deallocate those. Same thing has happened to me when using Celery -- need to restart the workers occasionally to prevent memory errors.

Comment: What dialect+driver are you using (e.g., `mysql+pymysql://`)?

Comment: @Gord Thompson I'm using Postgresql through flask-sqlalchemy.